# Key-dependent cipher generation

Tags: algorithm-design, symmetric, information-theory, computational-complexity-theory

Is there any cryptanalysis possible if the cipher itself is deterministically derived from key material?

For example, suppose you have n building blocks (ARX primitives, AES ops, other primitives) and parameters to further modulate them (ex. rotation numbers).

How could you even attempt to cryptoanalyze such a cipher?

In the extreme case, you could craft the cipher from the simplest of atoms (cpu ops) based on key material. So you end up with an completely unknown mapping function (block cipher) constrained by some build rules. Is some security reduction to NP-hardness possible there?

Comment: What did happen to linear and differential attacks on block ciphers?

Comment: If the execution (i.e. the sequence of operations) of the algorithm is dependent on the key, how are you suppose to protect it from side-channels?

Comment: There is also the issue that keys are random, thus a key-based assembly of "the simplest of atoms (cpu ops)" would lean towards a random program, and this would tend to make a poor cryptographic primitive for a sizable fraction of keys. Donad E. Knuth wisely noted: “Random numbers should not be generated with a method chosen at random", and that extends to all cryptographic primitives.

Comment: We have data-dependent rotations in RC5 and RC6, and at least in later rounds this is dependent on the key.  However, they are subject to side-channel problems if the CPU lacks a barrel shifter.